# Using firebase realtime database my entries are around 300 items. now not getting response from firebase in datasnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `Firebase realtime database` in my android app. My entries in table is around 300. I'm not able to get the data from the `Firebase` in `Datasnapshot`. Sometimes it works after loading 20 minutes. How can I access my data & response fast. It's working well & very fast in `iOS` with same database & same queries.

```
private void checkBookingInfo() throws Exception {

    mDatabaseReference.child(FireBaseConstants.BOOKING_INFO_TABLE).limitToFirst(10).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                countArrival = 0;
                countDeparture = 0;

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //check  arrivals date matches with today's date then increment counter
                    if (snapshot.hasChild(FireBaseConstants.ARRIVAL_DATE)) {
                        String currentDate = Utils.getCurrentDate();
                        String arrivalDate = snapshot.child(FireBaseConstants.ARRIVAL_DATE).getValue().toString();
                        String status = snapshot.child(FireBaseConstants.STATUS).getValue().toString();

                        if (currentDate.equalsIgnoreCase(arrivalDate) && !status.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancel")) {
                            countArrival++;
                        }
                    }
                    //check  departure date matches with today's date then increment counter
                    if (snapshot.hasChild(FireBaseConstants.DEPARTURE_DATE)) {
                        String currentDate = Utils.getCurrentDate();
                        String departureDate = snapshot.child(FireBaseConstants.DEPARTURE_DATE).getValue().toString();
                        String status = snapshot.child(FireBaseConstants.STATUS).getValue().toString();
                        if (currentDate.equalsIgnoreCase(departureDate) && !status.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancel")) {
                            countDeparture++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                setValueInEditText();
            } else {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("notme", "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have reached your limit, check usage and make sure you have requests left.

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance of the Firebase query you can add index on the field by which you are ordering Your query. Like

```
  {
   "rules": {
      "YOUR_NODE": {
         ".indexOn": ["FIELD1", "FIELD2"]
     }
   }
  }
```

You can find the helping link [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

Firebase also says [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

> Important: The onDataChange() method is called every time data is
>   changed at the specified database reference, including changes to
>   children. To limit the size of your snapshots, attach only at the
>   highest level needed for watching changes. For example, attaching a
>   listener to the root of your database is not recommended.

But even if the index is not applied still 20 minutes is much time, you need to check your source code there could be some other issue in the UI, may be data is coming but not populating in the UI.